# Dart Web UI - Passing object data to a component

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I am trying to pass data to custom component. 
The example at http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/#pass-data-to-component works good.

But I'm trying to pass a JsonObject var, and it crash with this message:

```dart
Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'JsonObject' of  'value'.
```

So it seems like I can pass only strings and numbers data?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me when passing the Map class. Perhaps you could change your code to use the [dart:json](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_json.html) library and the core library Map class, rather than the third-party [JsonObject](https://github.com/chrisbu/dartwatch-JsonObject).

JsonObject also uses the mirrors library, which is not yet supported in dart2js, so may not be a good fit for browser based development.