# Dart bind JsonObject error: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'JsonObject' of 'value'

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have a main GLTkComponent
============= xgltk.dart GLTkComponent.dart ==================================

```dart
@observable
class GLTkComponent extends WebComponent {

  ObservableList<JsonObject> ListTk = toObservable(new ObservableList<JsonObject>());

  JsonObject currentRow;

  cm.ViewType currentView;

  inserted() {
    populateAccountsTable();
    currentView = cm.ViewType.LIST;
  }

  populateAccountsTable() {
    ServiceStack.get("http://localhost:9998/dmtk").done((results) {

      JSON.parse(results).forEach((data) {
        JsonObject currentRow = new JsonObject.fromMap(data);
        ListTk.add(currentRow);
      });

    }).fail((e)=>print("Error in xgltk.populateAccountsTable() ${e}")).go();

  }
}
```

============= xgltk.html ===========================================

```dart
...
<body>
    <element name="x-gltk" constructor="GLTkComponent" extends="div">
      <template>
        <div class="container-fluid"> <!--list -->
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <template instantiate="if currentView == cm.ViewType.LIST">
              <x-gltk-list bind-list="ListTk" bind-current="currentRow" bind-view="currentView"></x-gltk-list>
            </template>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- end div list -->

      </template>
      <script type="application/dart" src="xgltk.dart"></script>
    </element>
  </body>
...
```

============ xgltk-list.dart GlTkListComponent ==========================

```dart
@observable
class GlTkListComponent extends WebComponent {

  ObservableList<JsonObject> list;

  JsonObject current;

  cm.ViewType view;

  inserted() {

  }

  String handleMenuClickClass(){
    if(current != null) {
      return "";
    }
    else {
      return "disabled";
    }
  }

  handleRowClick(JsonObject row) {
    current = list.firstWhere((e) => e.Tk == row.Tk);

    assert(list is ObservableList<JsonObject>);
    assert(current is JsonObject);
  }

  String handleRowClickClass(JsonObject row){
    if(current != null) {
      return row.Tk == current.Tk ? "info" :"";
    }
    else {
      return "";
    }
  }

  AddNew() {
  }
}
```

======================= xgltk-list.html ===========================

```dart
---
<body>   
    <element name="x-gltk-list" constructor="GlTkListComponent" extends="div">
      <template>
        <div id="id_list">   <!--div list -->
          <div class="span8" id="content">
            <table class="table table-hover" id="id_list_table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Tài khoản</th>
                  <th>Tên tài khoản</th>
                  <th>Ngoại tệ</th>
                  <th>Định khoản</th>
                  <th>Công nợ</th>
                  <th>Sổ cái</th>
                  <th>Tk Mẹ</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody template iterate="row in list">
                <tr on-click="handleRowClick(row)" class="{{handleRowClickClass(row)}}">
                  <td>{{row["Tk"]}}</td>
                  <td>{{row["Ten_Tk"]}}</td>
                  <td>{{row["Ma_Nt"]}}</td>
                  <td><template instantiate="if row['Loai_Tk']"><i class="icon-check"></i></template></td>
                  <td><template instantiate="if row['Tk_Cn']"><i class="icon-check"></i></template></td>
                  <td><template instantiate="if row['Tk_Sc']"><i class="icon-check"></i></template></td>
                  <td><template instantiate="if row['Tk'] != row['Tk_Me']">{{row["Tk_Me"]}}</template></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>  <!-- div list -->
      </template>
      <script type="application/dart" src="xgltk-list.dart"></script>
      <!-- for this next line to work, your pubspec.yaml file must have a dependency on 'browser' -->
      <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    </element>
  </body>
---
```

When i clicked on List it has error :

```dart
web_ui.observe: unhandled error calling Closure: (dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic from <observer 56>.
error:
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'JsonObject' of 'value'.

stack trace:
#0      GLTkComponent.currentRow= (http://127.0.0.1:3030/Z:/future13/3SNext/web/out/xgltk.dart:126:29)
#1      GLTkComponent.created_autogenerated.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (http://127.0.0.1:3030/Z:/future13/3SNext/web/out/xgltk.dart:62:56)
#2      DomPropertyBinding._safeSetter (package:web_ui/templating.dart:360:11)
#3      DomPropertyBinding.insert.<anonymous closure> (package:web_ui/templating.dart:369:58)
#4      _ExpressionObserver._runCallback (package:web_ui/observe/observable.dart:556:16)
#5      _ExpressionObserver._deliver (package:web_ui/observe/observable.dart:640:17)
#6      deliverChangesSync.deliverChangesSync.<anonymous closure> (package:web_ui/observe/observable.dart:435:58)
#7      SplayTreeMap.forEach (dart:collection/splay_tree.dart:209:8)
#8      deliverChangesSync.deliverChangesSync (package:web_ui/observe/observable.dart:435:33)
#9      setImmediate.<anonymous closure> (package:web_ui/src/utils_observe.dart:29:13)
#10     _ReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:81:92)
```

How to fix it. Please help me.
Thanks you very much.

Tuan Hoang Anh

Comment: Hi - JsonObject author here.  Can you share an example of the JSON text that you're passing into `JSON.parse(results).forEach((data) {`

Comment: here is it : [{"Tk":"111","Ten_Tk":"Tiền mặt"...}, ..........{"Tk":"911","Ten_Tk":"Xác định kết quả kinh doanh"...}]

Comment: xgltk-list.html can be display, but error when bind-value GlTkListComponent.current back to GLTkComponent.currentRow. Maybe @observable can not support JsonObject.

Comment: Is it same problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589757/dart-web-ui-passing-object-data-to-a-component/15592762#15592762

Comment: is "currentRow" of GLTkComponent getting set from somewhere else? otherwise I would expect it to be null, because `JsonObject currentRow = new JsonObject.fromMap(data);` just sets a local variable. Maybe you meant `currentRow = new JsonObject.fromMap(data);` ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite reproduce what you're showing with the data provided, but I think what the error message

> type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'JsonObject' of 'value'.

is telling you is that at some point `currentRow` is containing a `List` instead of a `JsonObject` when you call `ListTk.add(currentRow)`

```dart
JSON.parse(results).forEach((data) {
    JsonObject currentRow = new JsonObject.fromMap(data);
    ListTk.add(currentRow);
});
```

This might be if your JSON looks like:

```json
[
  {"Tk":"111","Ten_Tk":"Tiền mặt"...},                 <-- Becomes a JsonObject
  {"Tk":"911","Ten_Tk":"Xác định kết quả kinh doanh"}, <-- Becomes a JsonObject
  [{...},{...}]                                        <-- Becomes a List
]
```

You could try adding a couple of `print` lines to help diagnose:

```dart
  print(data); // output the actual data that JsonObject is going to convert from
  print(data is Map); // expecting true
  var currentRow = new JsonObject.fromMap(data); 
  print(currentRow.runtimeType.toString()); // expecting JsonObject
  ListTk.add(currentRow);
```

Comment: I keep one row in table and here is new data : {Tk: 111, Ten_Tk: Tiền mặt, Ma_Nt: VND, Loai_Tk: false, Bac_Tk: 1, Tk_Sc: true, Tk_Cn: false, Tk_Me: 111, Rec_Version: 14218, Rec_Id: 14173, Rec_Create: 2013-07-13T09:20:54.0280000, Rec_Created_Id: 1, Status: 1, Rec_Modified: 2013-07-13T09:20:54.0280000, Rec_Modified_Id: 1}. Error is happened

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here is my output print(data) : {Tk: 111, Ten_Tk: Tiền mặt, Ma_Nt: VND, Loai_Tk: false, Bac_Tk: 1, Tk_Sc: true, Tk_Cn: false, Tk_Me: 111, Rec_Version: 14218, Rec_Id: 14173, Rec_Create: 2013-07-13T09:20:54.0280000, Rec_Created_Id: 1, Status: 1, Rec_Modified: 2013-07-13T09:20:54.0280000, Rec_Modified_Id: 1}. print(data is Map) : true. print(currentRow.runtimeType.toString()) : JsonObject. But error is happened

Comment: Error is happened when pass currentRow between GLTkComponent and GLTkListComponent. Maybe @observable can not support JsonObject.